# Code conversion issue in DB2

Tags: internationalization, db2

I am using putty to connect AIX server where we have DB2 product.
When I have changed the translation settings in putty as ISO-8859-8:1999 (Latin/Hebrew), I am getting the proper hebrew character result.But, when I am changing the translation setting as utf-8, I am getting the different result. Even in front end we are getting the different results. Kindly help us to resolve this issue. Please refer the attachements for the proper and wrong results..

[image: Proper Result]

[image: Wrong Result]

Thanks and Regards!!!
Ananth Francis

Comment: What does it have to do with DB2? Your images are not showing, but I would venture to guess that you are missing an appropriate font on your workstation.

Comment: The attachment does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are only sure about what is inserted in the database, if you check the hexa code. The encoding of the terminal could be different, and that creates this kind of problems.

Make sure your applications and terminals are using the same encoding. Even if Putty shows the right character it does not mean that it is stored the same thing in the database.